# SOAP::Lite webservice request

Tags: xml, perl

I've got the following xml output from a valid soap request that I need to convert to perl. I've created other soap requests successfully by adding the parameters but this is different in that there are attributes of xml elements that is creating a problem for me. This is the request.

```
<SendNotificationRequest clientIndicator="ISAAC_WFE" language="en" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://edd.att.com/cnmeddservice EDD_Request.xsd"            xmlns="http://edd.att.com/cnmeddservice" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
<ctype>TXT_TO_MGR</ctype> 
<ctn category="contact">917523xxxx</ctn> 
<data> 
<dataField name="MgrID">jz359m</dataField> 
<dataField name="SMSText">this is a test SMS message</dataField> 
</data> 
</SendNotificationRequest>
```

This does not work and I think its due to the 'category' and 'name' fields being an attribute of an xml element, not an element itself. So please let me know if this is anything close to what I needed.

```
$self->{method_name} = 'SendNotificationRequest'; 
$self->{method_attr} = { 
  "clientIndicator" => 'ISAAC_WFE', 
  "language" => "en", 
  "xsi:schemaLocation" => 'http://edd.att.com/cnmeddservice EDD_Request.xsd', 
  "xmlns" => 'http://edd.att.com/cnmeddservice', 
  "xmlns:xsi" => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', 
  "xmlns:cnm" => 'http://edd.att.com/cnmeddservice', 
}; 

my $data = SOAP::Data->name($self->{method_name})->attr($self->{method_attr}); 
my @params = ( $data =>( 
SOAP::Data->type("")->name('ctype' => 'TXT_TO_MGR'), 
SOAP::Data->type("")->name('ctn')->attr({'category'})->value(SOAP::Data->value([ 
SOAP::Data->name('contact' => '917523xxxx')])), 
SOAP::Data->type("")->name(data => 
\SOAP::Data->type('')->value( 
SOAP::Data->type('')->name('dataField')->attr({'name'})->value(SOAP::Data->value([ 
SOAP::Data->name('MgrID' => 'jz359m')])), 
SOAP::Data->type('')->name('dataField')->attr({'name'})->value(SOAP::Data->value([ 
SOAP::Data->name('SMSText' => 'this is a test SMS message')])), 
)))); 
$self->{content} = $soap->call(@params); 
$self->{request} = $soap->serializer->envelope(method => $data, @params);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Soap::Lite](http://search.cpan.org/~byrne/SOAP-Lite/lib/SOAP/Lite.pm) page

```
print SOAP::Lite
  -> new(....)
    -> call(SOAP::Data->name('method')->attr({xmlns => 'mynamespace'})
        => @parameters)
    -> result;
```

So do you need

```
SOAP::Data->name('ctn')->attr({category =>'contact' })
    ->value(SOAP::Data->value('917523xxxx'))
```

If you can post a SOAP url then it will easier to help